# How to ignore an employer by name?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, jobs

Is there a way to subtract certain employers from the job listings? There are some positions there by companies that keep getting reposted, and I'm not interested in seeing them repeat themselves.

Comment: Wow that garnered support rather quickly.

Comment: On a similar note - is it possible to just get employers and not agencies?

Comment: @monsky We're discussing this - more to come.

Answer (score 7):

We can see how this can be a neat addition. Status-planned. We have some more employer related stuff coming up and will work on it then.

Answer (score 4):

We have some basic Boolean in place, using “-” to negate a search term. An example:

Before: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java&location=seattle (dominated by Amazon)

After: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+-amazon&location=seattle

Comment: But `-amazon` would also exclude any offers that mention *using* Amazon cloud services? (I'm not using Careers.)

Comment: @Arjan Yes it would, perhaps a bad example since “amazon” might refer to a company *or* a technology. But this would be an issue in most search engines if you negate a term.

Comment: Doesn't feel like status completed then?