# That amazon fills all search results

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Try to search java + relocation offered, first page is totally occupied by amazon postings. I can't see anything else. Please allow to filter out companies by names.

Comment: `java + relocation -amazon` seems to work... http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+%2B+relocation+-amazon&location=

Comment: (@dhblah, see comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107006/how-to-ignore-an-employer-by-name/213432#213432).)