# Ignore company in careers website

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Please add a feature to ignore spamming companies from the jobs list.

Comment: Why not just boot them off?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of that verb, do you mean "ignore them"? It's annoying. Plus when I see "C++ remote work" I get excited but then I get a strong delusion when I also see the company name.

Comment: If you mean exclude from search, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107006/how-to-ignore-an-employer-by-name).

Comment: Can you give examples as Pops said? What is your definition of spamming?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "spamming companies" here, but it doesn't sound good. Some more details would probably be helpful. Feel free to get in touch with us at team@stackoverflow.com if it involves stuff you don't want to discuss in public.

In the general case, if a company is treating users badly on Careers, I don't think ignoring the company is the right move. We want to know about it so we can correct the company's behavior... or discontinue our relationship with them, if need be. Stack Overflow is dedicated to making developers' lives *better*, after all.